# Char.IsDigit() vs Char.IsNumber(), what's the difference?

Tags: c#, validation, char

What's the difference between `Char.IsDigit()` vs `Char.IsNumber()`

Comment: From MSDN: *"[`IsDigit`] determines whether a `Char` is a radix-10 digit. This contrasts with `IsNumber`, which determines whether a `Char` is of any numeric Unicode category. Numbers include characters such as fractions, subscripts, superscripts, Roman numerals, currency numerators, encircled numbers, and script-specific digits."* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0ddtxh.aspx

Comment: If `MSDN` was clear `StackOverFlow` was not so popular

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
// 1/2 symbol
Char.IsNumber('½'); // true
Char.IsDigit('½'); // false

// Unicode character for Roman numeral 5 (V)
Char.IsNumber('\x2165'); // true
Char.IsDigit('\x2165'); // false
```

Comment: What about ³ ("superscript three")? I once ran into a bug in another language where IsDigit recognized the three superscripts as digits, causing me a small world of pain (mostly because their `value - '0'` was over 130 and not somewhere between 0 and 9 as I expected)

Comment: Tried the superscript 3 in LINQPad and it returns false for IsDigit.  But here's a list of characters that should return true: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm